# Additivity Implies Homogeneity of Rational Scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, irrational-numbers

I did my best to search for this question on the site- but I did not find it. Here it is:

> If a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f(\frac{p}{q}v)=\frac{p}{q}f(v)$ for all $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, $q\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$.

So far, I have tried to use argument substitutions and "abuse" of additivity to achieve a homogeneity condition. For example:
$$ f\bigg(\frac{p}{q}v\bigg)=f\bigg(\frac{p-q}{q}v+v\bigg)=f(v)+f\bigg(\frac{p-q}{q}v\bigg)$$
and other similar things- but I have been unable to show this.

**Note:** I only want a gentle nudge in the right direction - I explicitly request that no one give me the answer.

Comment: Start by showing that $f(nv)=nf(v)$ for positive integers $n$. Then for all integers. Then fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$f$ satisfies
$$
f(nv)=nf(v)
$$
and
$$
nf(\frac{1}{n}v)=f(v)
$$
for every positive integer $n$ and for every $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$. (Why?)